# re.sub() behaves weirdly when group name is specified

Tags: python, regex, replace, regex-group

I wanted to replace dots (`'.'`) with a sequence of characters, e.g. `foo.bar` > `fooDOTbar`, but only when the dot was not between two numbers, e.g. `0.9` > `0.9`. So I did:

```
regex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z])(?P<dot>\.)([a-zA-Z])')
input_str = 'foo.bar'
output = regex.sub(r'DOT\g<dot>', input_str)

print(output)
'foDOT.ar'
```

Which is not at all what I was expecting. I tried to replace `.sub()` with `.search()` it seems to work just fine (`match.group('dot')` returns `'.'`).

Comment: The regex you have bahaves  as expected. You only used `dot` group backreference, so the letters captured with Group 1 and 3 are gone. If you use `output = regex.sub(r'\1DOT\g<dot>\3', s)`, it will output `fooDOT.bar`. However, I believe all you need is `re.sub(r'(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)', '', s)`

Comment: @PatrickArtner I didn't copy-past my code, clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a named capture for something you know you're going to throw away? I'm talking about `(?P<dot>\.)`. This is how you'd do it:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?P<before>[a-zA-Z])(\.)(?P<after>[a-zA-Z])')
>>> regex.sub(r'\g<before>DOT\g<after>', input)
'fooDOTbar'
```

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the behavior of \g<group>. My understanding was that only that group would be replaced, not that I could use it as reference in repl.

Answer (score 1):

Or without using group:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\.)(?=[a-zA-Z])')
input_str = 'foo.bar'
output = regex.sub(r'DOT', input_str)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
fooDOTbar
```